# Integral $\int\sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having a bit of trouble with integration by substitution so I've plugged $\int\sec^2(\frac{x}{2}) dx$ into Wolfram and can't understand their solution steps.

They have said to let $u= \frac{x}{2}$ which I can follow.

So we now have $\int\sec^2(u)dx$

The next step I can't grasp.

They said to substitute du for $\frac{1}{2}dx$

I can see the dx in the equation, but where is the 1/2 that I'm also substituting? And from there how does the equation all of a sudden become $2\int\sec^2(u)dx$?

Thanks

Comment: Just because you set $x=2 u$; then $dx=2 du$. Now, replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $1=\frac22=2\cdot\frac12$. So,

$$dx=1\,dx=2\cdot\frac12dx=2\,du.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the rule:
$$\int \sec^2 v dv= \tan v+c.$$

Then, for $\int \sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx$, we have that 
$$v=\frac{x}{2}\Rightarrow dv=\frac{1}{2}dx\Rightarrow dx=2dv $$
and
$$\int \sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx=\int \sec^2v (2dv)=2\int \sec^2v dv=2\tan v+c=2\tan \frac{x}{2}+c. $$